# Set view to current location by clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet, html-framework-7

I have a project using React, react-leaflet and Framework 7. In one component I have a Fab-Button from Framework 7 and a Map from react-leaflet. My Map.jsx component looks like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMapEvents, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "../css/leaflet.css";
import "../css/app.css";
import {Fab, Icon, PageContent} from "framework7-react";

export default function Map(){

    function LocationMarker() {
        const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
        const map = useMapEvents({
            click() {
                map.locate()
            },
            locationfound(e) {
                setPosition(e.latlng)
                map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
            },
            locationerror(e) {
                alert("Unfortunately, we could not find your location")
            }
        })

        return position === null ? null : (
            <Marker position={position}>
                <Popup>You are here</Popup>
            </Marker>
        )
    }

    function fabGoToCurrentPosition() {
        //probably something like this:
        map.locate()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Fab position="right-bottom" slot="fixed" id="fab-button" onClick={() => {
                fabGoToCurrentPosition()
            }}>
                <Icon f7="placemark_fill" ios="f7:placemark_fill" aurora="f7:placemark_fill"></Icon>
            </Fab>
            <PageContent className='page-content-map'>
                <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true} id="map">
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <LocationMarker/>
                </MapContainer>
            </PageContent>
        </>
    );
}
```

The function "LocationMarker" is from a react-leaflet tutorial and sets the position of the Map to the current location of the user if the Map is clicked. My aim is that the position is set if the user clicks the Fab-Button instead of the Map.